Eloqua CDO and Activities Link
I have Contact that is linked to multiple CDO's in eloqua, So Is there any possibility way to link CDO and Activities directly without Using Contacts or Accounts.
( Can't we add CDO id directly to activities field so while exporting Actvities back I can get CDO id and get the Actual Data present in CDO )
or
Is there any possible way to get CDO Details while exporting bulk Activities
